# google cloud java api to connect to gke and execute kubenetes commands to get secrets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am new to google cloud platform and kubernetes in gcp. I am writing a java client code to connect to gcp and retrieve kubernetes secrets for some automation. Can someone please advise a good sample or documentation to start with?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack overflow prefers questions where some effort has been made to progress the solution to resolution, code is outlined and problems shown. Google's documentation is extensive and submitting a question that could be answered more effectively by reviewing documentation is discouraged.

Comment: Your question is also unclear. Kubernetes is a software solution. Google Cloud Platform (GCP) services can be used to run Kubernetes. Users can (a) run (and manage) Kubernetes on Compute Engine VMs directly; (b) use Google's managed offer called Kubernetes Engine; (c) indirectly use Kubernetes through Cloud Run. GCP includes a Secret Manager offering. Kubernetes includes a resource type called Secrets. I assume (!?) that you wish to access Kubernetes Secrets. If so, then one option for you to consider is using [Kubernetes Java client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java).

Comment: Thanks for your response DazWilkin. Apologies, I was not able to paste my code that I am seeing issues due to limitations posting from company's laptop. Will recreate in my personal laptop and post it.

Answer (score 0):

D'y'mean [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/secret#:%7E:text=kubectl%20get)?

Also, if it's Kubernetes on GCP, it's best to mention it as GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) unless you mean to say that you're including a Kubernetes instance inside of a GCE (Google Compute Engine) instance, in which case you treat it as a Kubernetes instance in another computer across the internet.

Lastly... I am going to flag this question. as @DazWilkin has explained that it is preferable to make some effort before asking.